# Sequence contains no element - Error when adding API Controller with Actions, using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Good day, does anyone encounter this problem? I'm using VS2022, ASP.NET CORE 6.0, Entity Framework Core and  Adding API Controller with Actions, using Entity Framework and receiving this Error "Sequence contains no element"

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUk12.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um3p7.png)

I did database first approach. Does any have solution on this? It will be very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: I would expect something like `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.2" />` but you have a PackageReference to EntityFramework 6.4.4 are you sure you are using EF Core consistently in your projects? (honestly, I don't know if this is a problem, since I didn't do much with EF core yet)

Comment: I'm stuck with this error right now. Did you find any solution?